# Oracle APEX: How to implement live automated chat with either webhooks, service workers or automation?

Tags: oracle-apex

Using the blog post:
https://apexapplab.dev/2022/08/25/creating-a-chat-region-in-oracle-apex/

I have created a chat for my users in my apex application.
Visually it works, as long as you either write a message or manually refersh the page.

To automate this process, the owner of the blog states, there are multiple ways of solving this:

- By running a Dynamic action that refreshes the Chat region every X seconds – the most straightforward and easy one, but not so user friendly
- By creating an Automation that runs every X seconds and updates a flag (might be an Application Global Item) if there are new messages. Then on the page with the Chat region – a Dynamic Action, running every X seconds and depending on the value of the Application Item, triggers a refresh of the Chat region – a bit more complex solution, but will trigger a refresh only when there are new messages, a lot better UX
- By using a Service Worker or Webhooks to “listen” for different events, such as new message being received. it could then trigger a specific action – that’s the most complex solution

It looks like to me, option 2 and 3, are the best ones to considers, however my problem is figuring out how to actually implement this, or where to find resources or explanations that are understandable.

Comment: I have looked at Automation in APEX, but it seemse to be limited to minutes or higher

Comment: I also have a feeling that a "Dynamic Action, running every X seconds...", means a dynamic action, that triggers a timed javascript function

Comment: Apologies if my description is a bit lacking, its just really hard to find good sources out there, regarding this topic within Oracle APEX

Comment: Currently working on a possible solution using Dynamic actions and AJAX call

Comment: In 23.1 - the upcoming apex release, there will be "APEX PWA Push Notifications". That will be a declarative feature. Maybe that could be used to implement a chat region.

Comment: Perhaps, I will need to read a bit more up on it :) The little I have found so far, points to it needing to be installed as a PWA app on the device, and requires the users approval (like most push notifications on the phone).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to option 2:

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but basically it runs an AJAX call every 5 seconds, that checks for a flag for the given chat.
If said flag is found (ie. true), it refreshes the chat region and scrolls to the bottom after a short delay. (Remember to also update the flag in your chat table to avoid repeating the refresh without a new message)

If said flag is not found (ie. false), nothing is done.

On page load dynamic action:

```
function checkChat () {
  apex.server.process(
    'CHECK_CHAT',
    {x01: apex.item("P1_CHAT_ID").getValue()},
    {
      success: function (pData) { 
        if(pData.includes('TRUE')){
          apex.region("mychatRegion").refresh();
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#mychatRegion .t-Region-body").scrollTop($("#mychatRegion .t-Region-body")[1].scrollHeight);
          }, 250);
        }
      },
      dataType: "text"
    }
  );
}


var intervalID = setInterval(checkChat, 5000);
```

AJAX Callback (CHECK_CHAT):

```
declare
  l_id number;
  l_flag boolean;
begin
  l_id := apex_application.g_x01;
  l_flag := chat_package.check_chat_flag(l_id);


  if(l_flag) then
    htp.p('TRUE');
  else
    htp.p('FALSE');
  end if;
end;
```

You will also need some code that updates this flag on your chat table whenever someone sends a message.